# Postgres won't shut down due to wal archiving

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I commanded Postgres to shut down using the init.d scripts (Linux) over 18h ago.

I can still see the processes running:

```
-bash-3.2$ ps -fe | grep postg
postgres  2299  3265  0 16:06 pts/5    00:00:00 ps -fe
postgres  2300  3265  0 16:06 pts/5    00:00:00 grep postg
root      3263 10185  0 May23 pts/5    00:00:00 su - postgres
postgres  3265  3263  0 May23 pts/5    00:00:01 -bash
root      5985 13676  0 May20 pts/3    00:00:00 su - postgres
postgres  5987  5985  0 May20 pts/3    00:00:01 -bash
postgres 14266     1  0 May23 ?        00:06:34 /usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/postmaster -p 5432 -D /var/lib/pgsql/9.1/data
postgres 14268 14266  0 May23 ?        00:01:51 postgres: logger process
postgres 14270 14266  0 May23 ?        00:01:30 postgres: writer process
postgres 14281 14266  0 May23 ?        00:00:09 postgres: archiver process   last was 000000010000028F000000A3
postgres 14282 14266  0 May23 ?        00:03:07 postgres: stats collector process
postgres 14283 14266  0 May23 ?        00:56:49 postgres: wal sender process postgres 10.40.227.238(12032) streaming 28F/A4000650
postgres 14306 14266  9 May28 ?        04:01:55 postgres: opera_man om 10.40.227.146(44745) SELECT
```

On the standby server (running normally) I see that:

```
$ ps -fe | grep postg
cluser   20724  7090  0 09:54 pts/0    00:00:00 psql -U postgres report
postgres 20726 21475  0 09:54 ?        00:01:12 postgres: postgres report [local] idle
postgres 21475     1  0 Apr24 ?        00:00:03 /usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/postmaster -p 5432 -D /var/lib/pgsql/9.1/data
postgres 21477 21475  0 Apr24 ?        00:00:01 postgres: logger process
postgres 21478 21475  0 Apr24 ?        05:34:10 postgres: startup process   recovering 000000010000028F000000A4
postgres 21485 21475  0 Apr24 ?        00:07:16 postgres: writer process
postgres 21486 21475  0 Apr24 ?        00:00:18 postgres: stats collector process
postgres 24091 21475  0 May23 ?        00:46:49 postgres: wal receiver process   streaming 28F/A40006E0
cluser   32136 30224  0 16:09 pts/16   00:00:00 grep postg
```

The log shows 'FATAL:  the database system is shutting down'. What could be the reason of this and how do I get it to run again?

Comment: if you send it to power off maybe you can do a `kill -9 <pid>` to do it ... then when you know that postgres is down you can start it again.....

Comment: @maniat1k You usually restart your DB server by unplugging it?

Comment: I know what you mean, but he already send the shutdown and it frozen on it... what else to do in this case?...

Comment: Server is not frozen it is saving wal files...

Answer (score 3):

The error message `FATAL: the database system is shutting down` is probably due  to new incoming connections that are denied because of the shutdown state of the master process.

According to [Shutting Down the Server](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/server-shutdown.html) in the documentation, for a fast shutdown, the existing server processes have received a `SIGTERM` signal to ask them to terminate as soon as possible.

Yet there is this process:

```
postgres 14306 14266  9 May28 ?        04:01:55 postgres: opera_man om 10.40.227.146(44745) SELECT
```

that does not want to quit.

You may try the next option, sending `SIGQUIT` to the master process (pid `14266`). This is likely to make it quit and it remains to be seen whether the subprocess with pid `14306` will quickly abort or stay stuck.

It it's stuck, I would kill it with `SIGKILL` as the last resort and then restart postgres normally with the init script.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try shutting the master down with "fast"?

```
/usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/pg_ctl stop -D /var/lib/pgsql/9.1/data -m fast
```

(yes, I realize that the restart iss hanging, but that's because the init script likely issued the restart with "-m smart")

Comment: The init script uses the 'fast' option:  $SU -l postgres -c "$PGENGINE/pg_ctl stop -D '$PGDATA' -s -m fast"  . The server is not actually crashed, it is saving wal files, I can see that the file name changes every now and then with 'ps'